# STM32 and H.264 compatibilty

Tags: video-streaming, stm32, h.264

Is it possible to encode a H.264 720P 24fps video with one of those STM32 Cortex ?

What should I be careful about ?

(I am using an OV7670 for the camera)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can encode h264 using a 8080, or a 6502, or even a piece of paper and a slide rule. It would just a really long time.

If you are asking if it can be done in real time, no.

Comment: But Is there any wildly available microcontroller who can do that?

Comment: No. Raspberry pi zero is the smallest thing I know of with h264 acceleration primitives.